# How to access the elements whose display is none and change their css property

Tags: jquery, html

I have set of `div` tags , whose property is display none with `<a>` tags inside those `div`'s.
Some of the `<a>` tag has `data-state="clicked"` property .

I want to access those `div`'s and change the diplay to block

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if(($(".display").attr("data-state") == "close") && (currenturl.indexOf("cl=true") != -1)){ 
    //I am trying to access the a tags whose attribute is clicked ,but the below is not working ... i think bse the display is none is not finding it
    var aInputs=$('a[data-state="clicked"]');
  }

  $("div").filter(function() {
    return $(this).parents('.childUI').css("display") == "none";
  });
});
```

I want to use the below function to get the `div`'s with display none and find `<a>` 
tag inside it with attribute `data-state="clicked"` and change its property to `display:block`..

I am in going in right way ? .. Any suggestion ?

**UPDATE** Here is the code ..

```
Before clicking
<div style="display: none;">
              <ul style="background-color:#DEECF7;" class="tert-nav">
                <li style="margin-left:1em" class="current childLink">
                  <a data-state="ntClicked" class="current" href="/businesscenter/recruitandhire/hiringadiverseworkforce/CareerPath.aspx?cl=true">CareerPath</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
```

After clicking

```
            <div style="display: none;">
              <ul style="background-color:#DEECF7;" class="tert-nav">
                <li style="margin-left:1em" class="current childLink">
                  <a data-state="clicked" class="current" href="/businesscenter/recruitandhire/hiringadiverseworkforce/CareerPath.aspx?cl=true">CareerPath</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
```

**Final Jquery**

```
 $('.childUI').filter(function () { 
           return $('.childUI').css('display') == 'none' &amp;&amp; $('.childUI').find('a').attr('data-state')== 'clicked'; 
          }).css('display', 'block').siblings('.display').attr({"class":"childLevelExpand","data-state":"open"});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following code will select all `divs`, will filter ones which have `display` as `none` and will change it to `block`

```
$('div').filter(function () { 
    return $(this).css('display') == 'none' && $(this).find('a').attr('data-state') == 'clicked'; 
}).css('display', 'block');
```

As mentioned in comments you can also use `.show`

Comment: @honk31 will it update it to `block` or `inline`? as `inline` is the default value

Comment: @honk31 Ohh didnt know that. Will update my answer accordingly

Comment: thanks for the reply.. i want to do above function ,only when the <a> tag inside the div has attribute data-state=clicked.... var aInputs=$('a[data-state="clicked"]'); line is not returning the result(object length is 0)

Comment: The function is not changing the display .. So i changed the as following     return $('.childUI').css('display') == 'none' &amp;&amp; $('.childUI').find('a').attr('data-state')== 'clicked';but the $('.childUI').find('a').attr('data-state') is always returning ntClicked as output.

Comment: It was overriding with my previous function ,changing the order fixed the above issue.

Answer (score 5):

jQuery has special selector to address hidden elements [:hidden](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/). Your filter function will be as simple as this:

```
$( "div:hidden").show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But i dont want to show all the hidden divs .i want to do above function ,only when the <a> tag inside the div has attribute data-state=clicked.... var aInputs=$('a[data-state="clicked"]'); line is not returning the result(object length is 0)